# Microsoft Visual Studio Professional Licensing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, licensing

We are planning to buy the Visual Studio Professional 2008 Edition to build some Proprietary 
software for ourself.
We have 3 developers working on this software.
The question is

**Can we distribute the application(just the exe) throughout the office?**

What are the restrictions?if any.

I went through the documentation provided by MS but its tought for me to digest or I did not get astraight forward answer
Any help Appreciated.

Can you please back your answers by some sort of Proofs(eg.links,docs etc ) from Microsft website?.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you need the professional version?  Visual Studio Express is free, and you can build any applicaitons you want and distribute them as much as you want.

All applications you build with visual studio have a royalty free, unrestricted license to distribute as you see fit.  If you buy an third party components they may have different licenses, but anything that comes with visual studio is freely redistributable (as long as you follow the rules for redistributing the runtimes).

UPDATE:

If you want "proofs" from Microsoft, just read the EULA

[Visual Studio 2008 Professional End User License Agreement](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdocuments%2Fuseterms%2FVisual%2520Studio_2008%2520Professional%2520Edition_English_473a7e16-65dc-4cfb-8f44-ebdd93cb1d3d.pdf&ei=HasSTJ-CK43LnAePy82RAw&usg=AFQjCNGeGrev2tpVbEpQrV0D-Y0QmUDO7w)

Comment: Does VS Express has Crystal Reports Support?

Comment: No, but SQL Server Express has built-in Reporting Services.  Also, it may be cheaper to use VS Express with a purchased third party reporting platform.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can distribute the application you build.

The licensing is for Visual Studio itself, which you may not distribute to more machines than you have licenses for.

Comment: +1 You can distribute the compiled application and libraires used, if any. You cannot distribute VS Pro itself, but I'm sure that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes,I meant the Applications Built using the VS 2008

Comment: Its getting Complex again,So Heres the Situation.
Say, I have developed a small addition application (say) and I cannot distribute it to all the people working in the office?Is that what you are saying?

Comment: When you develop that small application, you can hand it out to everyone on the planet.

Comment: @Rangoric You have good Sense of Humor? :)

Comment: @ThinkingCap: Why? He is serious...

Comment: What you build in Visual Studio is pretty much your decision on how to license it - that's what building software is all about!

Comment: @ThinkingCap Yeap, and I wanted to show the extreme of what you can do.

Answer (score 4):

You still sound confused, so maybe if we use an analogy.  Photoshop is used to create images.  Let's say you buy 3 licenses to Photoshop, so that you can install Photoshop on 3 artist's machines.  The artist make some images with Photoshop.  The images can be distributed to anyone, througohut your office.  The license only applies to the Photoshop application you installed.  The images you create with the Photoshop application can be distributed as you see fit.

So, the licenses you own for Visual Studio give you the right to install the Visual Studio application on the developers machines that you bought licenses for.  The developers then write some code, and compile that code into a new program.  That program they compiled is their creation, and can be distributed however you want.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limitation to the distribution of the applications built with Visual Studio, so yes, you can without concern.

By the way: Why VS 2008 and not VS 2010?

Comment: Can you please explain,What restricions apply in terms of Number of machines it can be installed and number of people using it?

Comment: e.g. you buy 3 licences which allows you to install it on 3 machines.

Comment: Visual Studio can be installed on as many machines as you have licences for it. The application you developed can be installed on as many machines as you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Visual Studio only on machines you bought licenses for. So in your case you should get 3 licenses.

This will let you build/compile/code application that can be used on as many computers you want. You can even sell that application to anyone.

If you don't need additional functionality you could use Free Express Edition too. It can be used for production as well.

Comment: I can claim I own Microsoft unless i have Documentation!!

Comment: @ThinkingCap You have the documentation.  It is in the license you purchased from Microsoft.

Comment: Is there anyway to purchase a developer license instead of a machine license? basically, I'd like to install VS 2010 Pro (if I buy it) on my desktop and on my laptop.  Of course I would only be able to use one at a time :)